# Jquery Syntax Error on Ubuntu Apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, ftp

I have set up a new Apache/MariaDB server stack on Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS. I have done this many times and have never experienced this issue.

When I attempt to host wordpress sites on this erver (that work fine on my online Ubuntu Servers) I get an unexplainable JQuery error:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" (line 3 of jquery.js)

There seem to be several illegal characters in the local jquery.js file. This also happens in another minified js-file on said site. I have tried forcing UTF-8 in the ftp client - this didnt help. When I copy the js-files via SSH they are not broken.

What could be the source of this issue? I am really at the end of my wits and probably missing something very simple...

..now that I mention it - I have never used ftp clients to copy sites on linux before (thats how I do it on windows). I have always done this via shell scripts. Somehow copying via ftp (filezilla) messes up my js-files. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I never actually figured out why this was happening. It probably has something to do with the settings of filezilla on my ubuntu.

I just went back to copying files via ssh or script.